# PPPoE & Normal connection

Tags: connection, windows-xp, windows-vista, pppoe

I have a problem. I got a Win XP machine and want to connect
it to my router which uses PPPoE. I wounder if it is possible
to connect both normally to my router with a cable & use the same cable for PPPoE?
The computer I am trying to connect does not have a wireless card, so I have to use the only one cable port. I wounder , if it can be done, how can it be done?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your description. You want to connect to the Internet via PPPoE and also connect, via the router, to this other machine? Where does the Internet connect to, the router or the XP machine?

Comment: The connection I thouhg about was like this

[ROUTER]-----[PC]
Via this one cable, I both want to run PPPoE and Normal connection